# Spring integration Java DSL : creating sftp outbound adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I want to create a flow using DSL. The flow is from channel and send to `sftp outbound adapter`. How do I send the mode of file? `REPLACE`

```
IntegrationFlows.from(uploadChannel())
                .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(sessionfactory())
                                .charset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
                                .remoteFileSeparator("\\")
                                .remoteDirectory(beaconSendProperties.getFtpLocation())
                                .fileNameExpression("payload.getName()")
                                .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                                .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                                .temporaryFileSuffix(".tranferring")
                                .fileNameExpression("fileNameGenerator")
                )
                .channel(uploadChannel())
                .get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `.channel(uploadChannel())` after `outboundAdapter` does not make sense and won't be reachable. Because `FileTransferringMessageHandler` is one-way `MessageHandler` and there is no `reply` to forward to the downstream flow.

The `REPLACE` can be achieved as the second argument for the overloaded `Sftp.outboundAdapter` method:

```
.handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(sessionfactory(), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
```

Comment: Thank you. .channel after I forgot to remove it :-)